# Tinymce open in a new tab whitespace error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, tinymce

I am using tinymce to generate an editor for a notes feature. As in there is a new note button on a page which redirects to a page containing an editor generated through tinymce.

This works fine while navigating in the same tab of a browser. But whenever I do the following steps:

- right click on new note option.
- open in new tab.
- then add some text and click on create note.

It simply creates a blank note. Which means that whatever text is written in the editor is not read by it.
I updated the tinymce gem, but with no output.

Can somebody help me out why this problem occurs only in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to reinitialize the tinymce instances correctly in case your change tabs

To shut down an edtor instance before changing tabs use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'your_editor_id');
```

To reinitialize the editor of the new tab use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'your_editor_id');
```

Comment: where exactly shall I implement these ?
1) inside the javascript ?
2) in the html page ?

Comment: you need to shut down tinymce everytime before you change tabs and reinitialize it everytime you load a tab with a tinymce editor

Comment: I am calling the above two functions through javascript. Every time when the page loads,these are called. But it is not working.